# Windows 10 Task Manager Slot indicator

Tags: windows-10, memory

On this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOT3m.png) I have circle the part where it says "*Slots used: 2 of 2* ". what does it mean? Possible to expand the number of slots, say from 2 to 6 or even 8??

Laptop Model: Ideapad S340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indicator means that your Ideapad has two physical memory slots and both are used.

Both my Lenovo laptops have 2 physical slots and 2 slots are used on both machines. Task Manager shows this the same as your screen shot.

> Possible to expand the number of slots, say from 2 to 6 or even 8?

No. The number of physical slots is an engineering design of the laptop and there will not be physical space or connections on the motherboard to add memory sockets.

You might be able to replace memory with higher capacity memory - I can do this on my X230 laptop and did.

If the memory is soldered in (my X1 laptop has the memory soldered in) then you are stuck with what you have.

Comment: Thanks! for sharing